# Hide registration and login form when user is logged in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am new at ASP.NET and I am having some difficulties. What I have below is a Registration and Login, both in one page. However, when a user is logged in, I would like the registration and login form to be hided.
There is a LOGOUT option when the user is logged in.
Any guidance would be great, thank you!

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs)

    End Sub



Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
</script>

<%-- Add content controls here --%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" 
    contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <table width="640px"><tr>
    <td width="360px">
                    <p>
                        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server">
                            <WizardSteps>
                                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" />
                                <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
                            </WizardSteps>
                        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</p>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </td>
                    <td width="270px">
                        <p>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Home.aspx">
        </asp:Login>
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                Please log In
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
</p>
    <p>
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to figure out if they're authenticated or not. If they are, you can set the visibility of your control to false.

In your Page_Load method, put something that looks like this:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            CreateUserWizard1.Visible = Login1.Visible = False
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. However I have built so far through examples-tutorials and I can not find any familiar. Please, if you have few minutes give me an example. Thanks!

Comment: Hey there thank you! Please let me know how can I modify this for user that is NOT logged in if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest LoginView.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
            <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
        </LoggedInTemplate>
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <p>
                <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
                </asp:Login>
            </p>
            <p>
            <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server">
                <WizardSteps>
                    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" />
                    <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" />
                </WizardSteps>
            </asp:CreateUserWizard>
           </p>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Hey there thank you! Please let me know how can I modify this for user that is NOT logged in if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:Login VisibleWhenLoggedIn="True|False" />

   Gets or sets a value indicating whether to show the Login control after the user is authenticated.

    For Example:
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="False"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Login Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
                VisibleWhenLoggedIn="false">
            </asp:Login>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```